# Использование PDO совместно с пространством имён в PHP

Tags: php, база-данных, ооп, pdo

Возникла проблема следующего характера: написал класс для работы с базой данных (драйвер - PDO), реализовал класс DBStatement (наследуемый от PDOStatement), чтобы указать на его использование, добавил атрибут *PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS*, всё работало, пока не решил использовать автозагрузку стандартом psr-4, указал namespace для класса базы данных и всё... Привет *use /PDO;* и куча проблем.
Ошибка, которую получаю в браузере:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS class must be a valid class in C:\OSPanel\domains\godour\classes\Database.php:32 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\godour\classes\Database.php(32): PDO->setAttribute() #1 C:\OSPanel\domains\godour\index.php(6): App\Core\Database::getInstance() #2 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\godour\classes\Database.php on line 32

Код файла Database.php:

```
<?

namespace App\Core;
use \PDO, \PDOException, \PDOStatement;

class Database
{
    protected static $instance = null;
    protected function __construct()
    {
    }
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {

            $databaseConfig = [
                "host" => "localhost",
                "port" => "3306",
                "user" => "root",
                "pass" => "",
                "base" => "game",
            ];

            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO(
                    "mysql:host=" . $databaseConfig["host"]
                        . ";port=" . $databaseConfig["port"]
                        . ";dbname=" . $databaseConfig["base"],
                    $databaseConfig["user"],
                    $databaseConfig["pass"]
                );
                self::$instance->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, ['DBStatement', [self::$instance]]);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
                self::$instance->query('SET NAMES utf8');
                self::$instance->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
            } catch (PDOException $error) {
                echo $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

class DBStatement extends PDOStatement
{
    public $db;
    protected $cachedObject = [];

    protected function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function execute(?array $params = NULL, bool $cached = false): bool
    {
        $this->cached = $cached;
        if ($this->cached) {
            $this->redis = new Redis();
            $this->redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
            $this->cachedObject = unserialize($this->redis->get(md5($this->queryString)));
            if (empty($this->cachedObject))
                $result = $params === null ? parent::execute() : parent::execute($params);
        } else {
            $result = $params === null ? parent::execute() : parent::execute($params);
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public function fetch(int $mode = PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT, int $cursorOrientation = PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT, int $cursorOffset = 0, int $expire = 3600): mixed
    {
        if (empty($this->cachedObject) && $this->cached) {
            $result = parent::fetch($mode);
            $this->redis->set(md5($this->queryString), serialize($result), ['nx', 'ex' => $expire]);
            return $result;
        } elseif (!$this->cached || empty($this->cachedObject)) {
            return parent::fetchAll($mode);
        } elseif (!empty($this->cachedObject) && $this->cached) {
            return $this->cachedObject;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

UPD

index.php:

```
<?

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

try {
    $db = App\Core\Database::getInstance();

    $sqlExample = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1';
    $stm = $db->prepare($sqlExample);

    $stm->execute([], $cached = true);

    var_dump($stm->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

Конфигурация composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "twig/twig": "^3.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Core\\": "classes"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: каждый класс должен быть в своём файле... с корректным путём......также, возможно, раз используешь `use` то для `PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS` обратного слэша уже не требуется (смотри подсказки в IDE).

Comment: А вообще наверное надо смотреть и файл загрузчика (что там , composer.json? или что-то ещё) и файл где всё подключается

Comment: Обратный слэш для PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS попробовал только сейчас, забыл убрать, без него результат, к сожалению, такой же.
composer.json добавил к теме

Comment: файл с кодом находится в папке `classes` ? Также, как я писал, каждый класс в отдельном файле?

Comment: Да, файл в папке "classes". Оба класса в одном файле, насколько знаю, PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS позволяет использовать только класс из этого же файла

Comment: Алексей, спасибо огромное! Моё недопонимание функциональности атрибута привело к потери большого кол-ва времени, вынес в отдельный файл второй класс, указал к нему путь через namespace и проблема была решена.

Comment: О, супер    %))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос был решён. Вынес DBStatement в отдельный файл (DBStatement.php), а для указания использования отредактировал входные данные атрибута *ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS*, указав ему пространство имён.
В итоге:

**Database.php**

```
<?

namespace App\Core;
use \PDO, \PDOException;

class Database
{
    protected static $instance = null;
    protected function __construct()
    {
    }
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (!self::$instance) {

            $databaseConfig = [
                "host" => "localhost",
                "port" => "3306",
                "user" => "root",
                "pass" => "",
                "base" => "game",
            ];

            try {
                self::$instance = new PDO(
                    "mysql:host=" . $databaseConfig["host"]
                        . ";port=" . $databaseConfig["port"]
                        . ";dbname=" . $databaseConfig["base"],
                    $databaseConfig["user"],
                    $databaseConfig["pass"]
                );
                self::$instance->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS, ['App\Core\DBStatement', [self::$instance]]);
                self::$instance->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
                self::$instance->query('SET NAMES utf8');
                self::$instance->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
            } catch (PDOException $error) {
                echo $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

**DBStatement.php**

```
<?

namespace App\Core;
use \PDO, \PDOStatement;

class DBStatement extends PDOStatement
{
    public $db;
    protected $cachedObject = [];

    protected function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function execute(?array $params = NULL, bool $cached = false): bool
    {
        $this->cached = $cached;
        if ($this->cached) {
            $this->redis = new \Redis();
            $this->redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
            $this->cachedObject = unserialize($this->redis->get(md5($this->queryString)));
            if (empty($this->cachedObject))
                $result = $params === null ? parent::execute() : parent::execute($params);
        } else {
            $result = $params === null ? parent::execute() : parent::execute($params);
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public function fetch(int $mode = PDO::FETCH_DEFAULT, int $cursorOrientation = PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT, int $cursorOffset = 0, int $expire = 3600): mixed
    {
        if (empty($this->cachedObject) && $this->cached) {
            $result = parent::fetch($mode);
            $this->redis->set(md5($this->queryString), serialize($result), ['nx', 'ex' => $expire]);
            return $result;
        } elseif (!$this->cached || empty($this->cachedObject)) {
            return parent::fetchAll($mode);
        } elseif (!empty($this->cachedObject) && $this->cached) {
            return $this->cachedObject;
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```